# What means 'scale' hyperparameter in SVM Polinomial (svmPoly method in caret)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, caret

I have searched in many places, and can't find what the hyperparameter 'scale' means in SVM polynomial in caret (method = svmPoly)

Caould you tell me, please?

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer :)